# variable scale of iterating for size_t

Tags: c, types, size-t

With a given `size_t`, what is the best data type for iterating for that?

```c
void do_some_for(size_t);
```

When I do with `int`,

```c
void do_some_for(size_t const size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    }
}
```

A kind compiler warns me like this.

```
....c:36:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                     ^
```

And putting `unsigned` before `int` clears the warning.

```c
void do_some_for(size_t const size) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    }
}
```

Now my question is what is the best (safe) data type to use?

I see `stdint.h#SIZE_MAX` prints this,

```
18446744073709551615 // at least 16 bits, i know.
```

which clearly equals to `2^63 -1`.

Should I use `unsigned long long int`(C99) for that? Or is there any dynamic way to do this?

Comment: Use `size_t` unless you have a cogent reason to do otherwise.

Comment: If the number of items to examine is given as a `size_t` value then the counter should also be `size_t`, with the usual precautions to be taken for unsigned types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use `unsigned long long int` for that?

You can't know, can you?  You might need 32 bits; you might need 64 bits.
(On a really old machine you might only need 16 bits.)

> Or is there any dynamic way to do this?

There is!  On every system there is a special type, with a system-specific definition, which is guaranteed to be:

- unsigned
- of an appropriate size to store the size of any object which you can manipulate on that system

And the name of this type is, of course, `size_t`.

So you should write

```
void do_some_for(size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and you should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, mate! Should I mind when I do an reverse iteration?

Comment: If you mean, do you have to worry if you were to write something like `for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)`, the answer is, yes, you absolutely do need to worry!  That's an infinite loop if `i` is unsigned.  (Fortunately good compilers will tend to warn about this sort of thing.)